# Internet explorer keeps crashing

Tags: internet-explorer, crash

Internet explorer 10-11 keeps crashing after I load it up.

Steps I have taken are

1. Disable addons
2. check for microsoft updates
3. downgraded to IE 10 to see if it still happens
4. Run Virus scans
5. updated all drivers to latest
6. reset ie

Here is a dump of what error I get

```
Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 10.0.9200.16720, time stamp: 0x523cf127
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18939, time stamp: 0x55afd843
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0002e423
Faulting process id: 0x1420
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e654daab4515
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

Any help will be appricated

Comment: capture a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/VDDuMrgb and share the dmp

Comment: have you captured the crash dump of IE?

Comment: Hi i have now discovered that there was a trojan on the system that has been casuing this that wasnt picked up by a few anti virus scans. i have decided to gt a new hdd and transfer over a few pics etc.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have now discovered that there was a trojan on the system that has been casuing this that wasnt picked up by a few anti virus scans. i have decided to gt a new hdd and transfer over a few pics etc. Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a couple of things:

1. clear all cache.
2. Run the Microsoft Mr. Fix it uninstall. (I don't actually know the link but you can actually do a search for it even from chrome).
3. You can also run at the command prompt in administrator mode: sfc /scannow
4. reboot.
5. download IE11 and follow the prompts.

The idea is within registry your configuration was corrupted (could be a number of different things). The above process more or less resets the state and health of your OS.

Good Luck,